# I need to update the text of a paragraph by inline edit

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've tried this

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h1>Some text here</h1>
    <p>Text area text here</p>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('p').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var txt = $(this).text();
        $(this).parent().append('<textarea>' + txt + '</textarea>');
        $(this).remove();
    });
});
```

I need to update the text of a paragraph by inline editing. I need to back the paragraph with the new text typed there and remove the textarea when someone click outside of the textarea.

Thanks

Comment: What is the question? You could also use the `contenteditable` attribute.

Comment: "I need to update the text of a paragraph by inline editing." . Where you want to edit ? In the textarea and updating in the paragraph ?

Comment: Take a look at the "contenteditable" attribute: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update to your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/99pxz8et/2/

what you need is to listen on change event for the new text area and then update it

```
    $area.one('focusout', function() {
        $p.show();            
        $p.text($area.val());
        $area.remove()                                
    });
```

Edit: changed .on() to .one()